# jQuery & history.js example

Tags: jquery, html, history.js

I'm having a little trouble using history.js with jQuery. I just wanted to make a navigation set work with the back button (which they do seem to be doing quite nicely). However. When I click the back button the url changes to the old (which again is good and what I want) but the content does not replace as it should.

To make this a little more understandable here's some code.

```
    <ul class="content_links">
        <li><a href="/historyapi/pages/content_page_1.html">Content page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/historyapi/pages/content_page_2.html">Content page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/historyapi/pages/content_page_3.html">Content page 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="/historyapi/pages/content_page_4.html">Content page 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="/historyapi/pages/content_page_5.html">Content page 5</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="content">
        <p>Content within this box is replaced with content from supporting pages using javascript and AJAX.
    </div>
```

Obviously what I want is the content of the pages load into content which is done nice and easily with .load() and then I want the back button to move backwards through them if the user uses it. At the moment the URLs change but the content in the box does not. How would I go about changing or fixing that?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<ul class="content_links">
    <li><a href="/historyapi/pages/content_page_1.html">Content page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/historyapi/pages/content_page_2.html">Content page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/historyapi/pages/content_page_3.html">Content page 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="/historyapi/pages/content_page_4.html">Content page 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="/historyapi/pages/content_page_5.html">Content page 5</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="content">
    <p>Content within this box is replaced with content from supporting pages using javascript and AJAX.
</div>

<script>
$(function() {

    // Prepare
    var History = window.History; // Note: We are using a capital H instead of a lower h
    if ( !History.enabled ) {
         // History.js is disabled for this browser.
         // This is because we can optionally choose to support HTML4 browsers or not.
        return false;
    }

    // Bind to StateChange Event
    History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function() { // Note: We are using statechange instead of popstate
        var State = History.getState();
        $('#content').load(State.url);
        /* Instead of the line above, you could run the code below if the url returns the whole page instead of just the content (assuming it has a `#content`):
        $.get(State.url, function(response) {
            $('#content').html($(response).find('#content').html()); });
        */
        });


    // Capture all the links to push their url to the history stack and trigger the StateChange Event
    $('a').click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        History.pushState(null, $(this).text(), $(this).attr('href'));
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Love your work man, worked a treat. Presumably I could wrap some say History.pushState(null, $(this).text(), $(this).attr('href')); in if(!History.enabled) to make sure it degrades gracefully or would the above suffice?

Comment: Also I would need to ensure cross domain links and https links we're checked properly, I guess?

Comment: The return false will make it degrade gracefully. And yes, you should check for external links within the $('a').click().

Comment: Yep, would also need to check for https links I guess. Come across anything good before?

Comment: Although I could just fine tune the ajax selector from $('a') to $('. content_links a') then it wouldn't really be an issue.

Comment: I would provide every link with a classname so you'd get something like $('a.ajax'). Changing it to $('.content_links a') would also do the trick.

Comment: @sroes i know this is an old post, but i just found out about history.js and am trying to figure things out. i copied your example and it works fine. but when i add history.js and you jquery code on my site, it don't seem to work. do all linked pages have to be just content being passed? instead of headers and footers?

Comment: @user2035819 yes, ideally only the content within #content should be returned in case of an ajax request (you can check this server side). If you don't have control over what's returned, you can change `$('#content').load(State.url);` to `$.get(State.url, function(response) { $('#content').html($(response).find('#content').html()); });`

Comment: wow, that's alot of code to change then. ALL my href's must be changed to return just content

Comment: @user2035819 No, all you're `a`'s clicks are being handled by the `statechange` event, so that code is only being replaced in that event

Answer (score 2):

it seems the following bit doesn't work:

```
$.get(State.url, function(response) {
  $('#content').html($(response).find('#content').html());
});
```

You have to convert the 'response' into a dom element before you can use 'find' on it. Like so:

```
$.get(State.url, function(response) {
    var d = document.createElement('div');
    d.innerHTML = response;
    $('#content').html($(d).find('#content').html());
});
```