# how to read from and update url hash changes in an ajax page keeping track of ajax queries in the url with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

i will like to be updating the browser url whenever i make an ajax query without reloading the page, so that one can easily go to the url and view the generated page through the url queries. using jquery.

Comment: [jQuery & history.js example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553037/jquery-history-js-example)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (typeof (window.history.pushState) == 'function') {
   window.history.pushState({ "html": response.html, "pageTitle": response.pageTitle }, "", urlPath);
   } else {
      window.location.hash = '#!' + urlPath;
   }
```

but Url PushState is not Support in I.E So u can use '#' Followed by your Url