# How to add hash history to a filterable portfolio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filtering

I am creating a filterable portfolio for my website. Once I click one of the filters it displays a hashtag at the end of my URL. For example if I click design it will display as www.yourdomain.com/#design.

Is it possible to make the browser back button work with that? That is, if I click this link, I add #design to my current address. Once I click the back button, the #design hash is removed and will display the last page or filter that was selected. Right now the back button works but it only displays all the filters that I selected in the URL but not on the page.

Is that somehow possible?

Here is a sample of the design that I am trying to work with http://www.jsfiddle.net/xnnnk/6/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".filter").click(function () {
        var filterText = $(this).attr('href').replace('#', '');
        $(".projectGrid").hide();
        $(".projectHolder").show();
        $(".projectHolder").not('.' + filterText).hide();
        $(".projectGrid").fadeIn(1500);
        $('.filter').not($(this).toggleClass('activeWork')).removeClass('activeWork');
    });
});
```

Thank you

Comment: html5 history object can help you with detecting click on back button, but that is not supported in all browsers yet

Comment: You might want to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553037/jquery-history-js-example/13553109#13553109

Comment: I did try that but and it goes back through the history appropriately, but doesn't update the page content to reflect the content appropriate to the hash @Fratyr

Comment: that does not seem to work with what I am trying to achieve when it comes to the hashtags @sroes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could detect the hash change e.g.

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
  console.log('changed to:'+document.location.hash);
});
```

and act accordingly, possibly call the filtering code you have posted.

This seems to be widely supported,
http://caniuse.com/#search=hash

Simple demo of what i've described,

http://jsfiddle.net/3nA2p/1

http://jsfiddle.net/3nA2p/1/show

Comment: @user3019846 very rough example, let me have a look and i will update.

Comment: @user3019846 i think it works fine the only thing not working is when returning to the first page with no hash and just added a condition checking that. But this is just a concept i'm sure you can make it much better.

Comment: now is there away once I refresh it stays on the assigned hashtag? @melc

Comment: @user3019846 yes just make an initial check on the hash of your `document.location.hash` if it is not empty then run your filtering code. It is best if you add the filtering code in a function it will come handy.

Comment: Here is a fiddle of what @melc is suggesting to do. http://jsfiddle.net/xnnnk/8/ This won't work in IE < 8

Comment: I did try that but it kept going back to the all portion of the site @BlakePlumb

Comment: Now i see why it didn't work, I forgot the period before trigger. I have been staring at this code way to long. @BlakePlumb

Comment: Now my hover active state has been removed because it depended on the $(".filter").click(function () { What other solution can I use to active this? @melc

Comment: @user3019846 Change the last line to `$('.filter').not($('[href='+location.hash+']').toggleClass('activeWork')).removeClass('activeWork');` http://jsfiddle.net/xnnnk/10/

Comment: How do I set a condition to check to see if there is a hash tag or not? Once I go back and it goes to the all page with out the hash it will not display @BlakePlumb

Comment: @user3019846 http://jsfiddle.net/xnnnk/11/  added a condition to `filterText` before using it. If it is empty then assign to it value `all`.